# javascript: create named function but its name is stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, instance

I have a situation in which I need at some point in my application the name of the constructor

```
instance.constructor.name
```

However, when I create the constructor I have its name stored in a variable. So, to give you an idea of what I want

```
var nameOfTheFunction = "Test" ;
var BarFoo = function() { /* do stuff */ } ;
BarFoo.name = nameOfTheFunction ;
```

This of course doesn't work, because the name property is read-only.

So is it possible to dynamically create a constructor function with the end result that the instances it creates will have

```
instance.constructor.name === nameOfTheFunction
```

UPDATE: checkout my comment below, because it does what I was looking for. For this questions though, thanks to the answer, I initially was looking for this

```
(new Function( 'base', 'return function ' + Foo.name + '(){ base.apply(this, arguments); };'))(Foo) ;
```

The problem with this solution is that the thing created here isn't an instanceof Foo, except when you do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/hE23T/3/), which brought me to the solution in my comment below!

Comment: I really don't know the benefits of this. Could you explain what you're trying?

Comment: you're right, I found an easier way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/8ztAU/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on the browser side, you could use the following solution :

[Javascript: Dynamic function names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178430/javascript-dynamic-function-names)

Of course this would make your function a global variable.

EDIT: If you absolutely want to use `eval`, you can use the following construct :

```
function generateFunction(functionName) {
    function __REPLACE__() {
        // your function's code
    }
    eval(__REPLACE__.toString().replace('__REPLACE__', functionName));
    return functionName;
}
```

Comment: Thnx for the link! I think that 'new Function' is better than 'eval'. Why do you think it makes global variables ? var Constr = new Function(){ 'return function' + name + '(){}'; }

Comment: If you declare a function as a property of Window, every object that has access to window (which is everything) has your function as a variable in his scope. You're right that `new Function()` is better than `eval()`.

Comment: With the second solution I wrote, you can write your function as a normal JavaScript function and than pass it as an argument to `generateFunction()`.

Comment: Note: Functions created with the Function constructor do not create closures to their creation contexts; they always run in the window context (unless the function body starts with a "use strict"; statement, in which case the context is undefined). From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `eval` is such a bad idea. But I would recommend, using a factory function, so you don't have to write all the code of your function in string literals:

```
function createNamedFunction(name, func) {
    eval("var f = function " + name + "(){return func.apply(this, arguments);};");
    return f;
}

var t = createNamedFunction("myFunc", function () {
    console.log("hello");
});

console.log(t.name);  //myFunc
t();  //hello
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ETQwt/)**

**EDIT**

You could also manipulate the string representation of your function directly, so you don't have to use the `apply` method:

```
function createNamedFunction(name, func) {
    var fstr = func.toString(),
        index = fstr.indexOf("(");
    fstr = "function " + name + fstr.substring(index);
    eval("var f = " + fstr + ";");
    return f;
}
```

Comment: do you think 'eval' should be used instead of 'new Function(){..}' ?

Comment: The reason is here @Jeanluca Scaljeri: Note: Functions created with the Function constructor do not create closures to their creation contexts; they always run in the window context (unless the function body starts with a "use strict"; statement, in which case the context is undefined). From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri I'm not sure how `new Function(){...}` would help you. As far as I know, it doesn't allow you to specify a name?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think we could use `eval`

```
var nameOfTheFunction = "Test" ;
var BarFoo = eval("function " + nameOfTheFunction + "() { /* do stuff */ }") ;
```

Comment: Eval is NOT a good solution ! DON'T USE EVAL ! It's not safe.

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek "It's not safe" isn't a related reason here. Either explain what you mean, or give a better reason

Comment: Eval is a security issue because you are executing untrusted source code. If an attacker could modify the parameters used in the string concatenation, they could execute malicious code in a users browser and run exploits, steal cookies ...etc.

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek `eval` is no more dangerous than your browser's console/developer tools. And who said anything about "untrusted" source code?