# MVC 4 Razor - Naming javascript functions dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to create the name of a function dynamically:

I set the name in razor code:

```
 @ { name="bob"; }
```

Then I try to create the javascript function, but the syntax is wrong.

```
function @name@:_onActivate() {
   .....
}
```

How can I use @name in the name of the function?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178430/javascript-dynamic-function-names

Comment: what about to use a html helper that output the javascript function as a mvsString based on your model, something like @Html.DynamicJavascript(Model)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was found to work in writing Javascript function names dynamically

```
@{
    @:function  
        @name<text>_onActivate() {
           ....
        }
   </text>
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I know im late to the party, but i had the same question and came up with this..

Use the @() Razor syntax:

function @(Model.Name)_Init()
{
    .....some code...
}

Works like a charm

(http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/)

Answer (score 1):

There is also another option:

```
@{
     var functionStart = "function " + name + "_onActivate()";
}

@functionStart
{
    ...
}
```

This method doesn't make so much mess in Visual Studio in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

This worked well for me:

```
@{
    var someFuncName          = "someFuncName";
    var someFuncName2         = "someFuncName" + Model.type;
    var someDynamicFunc       =  Model.funcName;
    var someFuncNameComplete  =  "functionHelper()";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function @someFuncName@{<text>()</text>}{
        ...
    }
    function @someFuncName2@{<text>(data)</text>}{
        ...
    }
    function @someDynamicFunc@{<text>()</text>}{
        ...
    }
    function @someFuncNameComplete{
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your JavaScript is in the view (rather than its own js file - though I'm not saying I think this is advisable), you can try wrapping your JS code in `<text>` tags, so that the parser switches back to HTML mode (vs C# mode).

Another alternative may be not naming the function dynamically but instead passing in the name as a parameter - but whether that would work may depend on your design/implementation.

Answer (score 0):

First you can set the function name in a string with below structure:

```
@{ 
    string name = "bob";
    string funcTxt = name + "_onActivate()"; 
}
```

Then you can use this string into your function declaration:

```
<script>
function @funcTxt {
    ...
}
</script>
```